# Count all received packet using Tshark

Tags: c#, wireshark, tshark

i am build application who start capturing via Tshark with command line and i am looking for option to count all the received packets after i am start Tshark process 
this is my function who start the process:

```
int _interfaceNumber;
string _pcapPath;


    Process tshark = new Process();
    tshark.StartInfo.FileName = _tshark;
    tshark.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(" -i " + _interfaceNumber + " -V -x -s " + _packetLimitSize + " -w " + _pcapPath);
    tshark.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    tshark.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    tshark.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    tshark.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
    tshark.Start();
```

maybe someone had an idea ?

Comment: What do you want to do with the packet count ultimately? Could higher-level statistics be more interesting (such as number of bytes per TCP connection)?

Comment: i want the packet count in order to show it ongoing in my UI, i don't think TCP connection hold this value

Comment: But what sort of conclusion do you expect from a mere packet count? I am asking because I think the count by itself is typically not very insightful, unless you are optimizing a network-layer device for packet throughput. If you look for a number that reflects network activity, a byte or host count (upstream/downstream) might be more appropriate. Also, if you want a live packet count in your UI, you may be better of with using `libpcap` directly.